# How to set Value in Global Variable?

Tags: java

I have declared variable on top after import

```
String sk5;
```

putted value in sk5

```
sk5 = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("-")+1).replace("]", "");

        System.out.println("Checking sk5->"+sk5);
```

It is printing value well, but when I am using this variable in other function it prints NULL.
please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: Its important where are you putting.. That should be called before you access its value..

Comment: it depends, is it an instance variable? how do you want to use it?

Comment: Use variable after you put something in it, then it will not print NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you want to define a class variable, so you should use

```
public static String sk5;
```

BUT defining a public static variable which is not final is a [bad code style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil).
If you want to use class variables in other classes, you should implement a getter-Method like

```
private static String sk5;

public static String getSk5(){
   return sk5;
}
```

and still a static variable is not the best.
Try to check [Singleton](http://www.theserverside.de/singleton-pattern-in-java/) instead, depending on our usecase it could make sence

from my point of view the best is to define

```
private String sk5;

public String getSk5(){
   return sk5;
}
```

so you can call

```
TestClass s = new TestClass();
String t = s.getSk5();
```

Comment: "Bad code style" is not a helpful thing to say by itself. Please explain why it's bad code style.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause for this problem is the assumption that all `sk5` variables are the same.  If you have multiple variables, or multiple instances, you actually have multiple fields/variables with the same name.

The simplest way to check this is to look at what your code is doing when you step thorugh it in your debugger.

[image]

You can see in the following example, you have three variables called sk5 with three different values.

```
class MyClass {
   int sk5;

   public static void main(String... s) {
     MyClass a = new MyClass(), b = new MyClass();
     a.sk5 = 1;
     b.sk5 = 2;
     int sk5 = 3;
     System.out.println(a.sk5+" " + b.sk5 + " " + sk5);
   }
}
```

prints

```
1 2 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using C#?

Normally, global variables are defined direclty after Class definition as shown here:

```
    class MyNewClass{
     public string newglobalval;
   public MyNewClass(){
    newglobalval = "Hello";
```

}

```
  public void ShowGlobalVal(){
    Console.Write(newglobalval);
```

}
}

Edit: Well, someone was faster, however the variable doesnt need to be static.

Peace.

Comment: This is the wrong programming language. he is asking about java